# Creating two generic parameters in an interface

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am trying to create a generic interface for my classes that will satisfy them all. I have created base classes to link them all together but the interface I'm trying to create isn't working like I'd expect it to and I cant find the right words to type into the search to find them.

The interface so far is:

```
public <T extends SDOBase> T entityToSDO(<? extends BaseEntity> entity, T sdo) throws Exception;
```

How do I make entity a second generic type?

Comment: I have two separate types that need to go in there and they both extend different base classes. The second wildcard is incomplete as I couldn't figure out the syntax to express what I needed.

Comment: Oh nevermind, I just re-read your code and posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try declaring your method this way:

```
public <T extends SDOBase, E extends BaseEntity> T entityToSDO(E entity, T sdo) throws Exception;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more along the lines of:

```
public interface MyInterface<T extends SDOBase>
{
    public T entityToSDO(<? extends BaseEntity> entity, T sdo) throws Exception;
}
```

Comment: `<? extends BaseEntity> entity` isn't valid syntax for a method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You just need

```
public <T extends SDOBase> T entityToSDO(BaseEntity entity, T sdo) throws Exception;
```

Anything that is an instance of a subtype of BaseEntity automatically is an instance of BaseEntity.